# How to add menu item to action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, r.java-file, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to add menu item to action bar.
**menu/main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/change_language"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="JP">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/lists"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Lists">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/collections"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_star"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Collections">
    </item>

</menu>
```

**change_language, lists** items are working perfectly. Menu item "collections" is not showing

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.change_language).setTitle("JP");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

It is not giving any error. I have checked R.java. There is no reference to "collections". Intellicence also not giving hints while writing "R.id.   "
How to add menu item to action bar? Maybe this is because, I published app to Google Play. However, I have set Debuggable to 'true'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`R.java` doesn't contain `id.collections`, it only contains `main.xml`, like this :

```
public static final class menu {
    public static final int main=0x7f0e0000;
}
```

Also, your app publishing and this issue are not related.

Where is your `R.id.change_language`? If you wanna create customized actionbar with icon and title, you have to modify your `main.xml` and add custom layout like below :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/collection"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/your_custom_layout"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="ActionBar"/>

</menu>
```

your_custom_layout.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/your_imageview"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_star" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/change_language"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

then, you can `findViewById` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` function.

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

> The showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in
>   the tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by
>   the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the
>   Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace
>   as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library.

So add this to your  tag ' xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" '

and set the showAsAction attribute like this: yourapp:showAsAction="always" in your items

Comment: Yes, it looks like this. I have other 2 menu item. They are working. But last added "collections" menu item not. I have no clue why.